# python class in string

Tags: python, class, methods

I have name of class in string like:

```
conf[0] = 'smtp_config'
```

and i want to run method like:

```
self.ui.smtp_config.setText("....")
```

How can i do this in python? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `getattr(self.ui,conf[0]).setText(...)`

Comment: +1 ...though a `hasattr` call first is probably preferable :)

Comment: Isn't hasattr roughly implemented by doing getattr and catching the exception anyway? Just call getattr. If the program can do something sensible if the attribute doesn't exist, catch the exception. If not, ignore it, and let the stack trace tell you about the bug when it turns out it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

```
func = getattr(self.ui, conf[0])
func.setText("....")
```